# Android TV Leanback app as default launcher

Tags: android, launcher, android-tv, android-launcher, leanback

So I am building a lean-back launcher app that will work on an android based streamer.

I've read all of Google's specifications in order to build a custom launcher.

Now in order of it to be a launcher, I need the app to behave as the default launcher of the streamer so it will be the first thing to open on boot.

I really couldn't find too much information regarding this subject when it comes to lean-back apps but only for normal mobile apps.

I've tried adding the HOME and DEFAULT categories to the MAIN activity in the manifest (as shown below) and it didn't work but I am also not even sure if this work only for mobile apps or lean-back apps as well because the lack of information I could find  -

```
<activity android:name=".activities.SplashActivity">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

In addition, I'd like to know if there is anyway doing this without asking the user to choose the default launcher but just making it as default automatically.

Thanks in advance for all the helpers.

Comment: Google allows operators (telcos, integrators, ...) to create their custom launcher. To enter this "Operator Tier" program you have to qualify as an operator and use an Android TV certified box. If that's your case I'd suggest you get in touch with your STB provider and/or Google to initiate this process.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered, it seems it is not possible to make any other launcher the default launcher if you will not disable/hide the default launcher first.

A few workarounds were posted, though I'm not sure if they will work for you. [Some installed home switcher applications](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidTV/comments/8vjfj8/how_to_change_launcher_for_android_tv_and/e1ogjxu/) and [some used adb shell commands](https://forum.xda-developers.com/shield-tv/themes-apps/alternate-launcher-root-marshmallow-t3359076). Do take note that some are saying that you need a rooted device, while some others say you do not.

Comment: As you assumed, its different from what I need but thanks for your time and willingness!